# Application of Ito's formula

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

I have the following process:

\begin{equation*}
X_t= \exp \left(\int_{0}^{t}s \, dB_s-\frac{t^3}{6} \right), 
\end{equation*}

where $B$ is a Browinan motion.

My textbook asks to write Ito's formula for $X$ and show that $X$ is a martingale.

I don't really know what the excercise wants, shouldn't I have some function so that I can write Ito's formula?

Comment: Set $\psi_t=\int_0^ts\,\mathrm dB_s-t^3/6$. Then $X_t=f(\psi_t)$ where $f=\exp$ is $C^2$ and $\psi$ is a semimartingale. Itô's formula thus applies.

Comment: Which version(s) of Itô's formula do you know?

Comment: @saz The one for Itō-processes

Comment: @user010010001 Well, $X_t := \int_0^t s dB_s-t^3/6$ is an Itô process, isn't it? So what do you get if you apply Itô's formula?

Comment: @saz I got: $dX_t=e^{\int_{0}^{t}sdB_s-t^3/6}dB_t+((\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2}t^2)e^{\int_{0}^{t}sdB_s-t^3/6})dt$

Comment: @user010010001 That's not correct. See my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For an Itô process $(X_t)_{t \geq 0}$ of the form

$$X_t-X_0 = \int_0^t \sigma(s) \, dB_s + \int_0^t b(s) \, ds \tag{1}$$

Itô's formula reads

$$f(X_t)-f(X_0) = \int_0^t f'(X_s) \sigma(s) \, dB_s + \int_0^t \left( \frac{1}{2} f''(X_s) \sigma^2(s) + f'(X_s) b(s) \right) \, ds.$$

Now:

1. $X_t := \int_0^t s \, dB_s - \frac{t^3}{6}$ is an Itô process. Choose $b$, $\sigma$ such that the representation $(1)$ holds.
2. Apply Itô's formula for $f(x) := \exp(x)$.

Comment: So $\sigma(s)=s$ and $b(s)=-\frac{1}{2}t^2$ ?
Then I applied Itō's lemma and got: 

$de^{X_t}=e^{X_t}dB_t-[(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{8}t^2)e^{X_t}t^2]dt$

Comment: @user010010001 your choice of $b$ and $\sigma$ is correct, but your calculations are still not correct. E.g. the first term should read $$e^{X_t} t \, dB_t.$$

Comment: thanks, after recalculating I got: $de^{X_t}=e^{X_t}tdB_t$

Comment: @user010010001 Yes, that's correct.